# Why Button Action is not Working inside a Textfield in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, return, textfield

I am having Three TextFields with Tag value 0,1,2.In the Third TextField I have added a Button Called `addbutton`.My Problem is,If i click the Third Textfield,KeyBoard is not coming.But Button action works. If i change the Return to YES means,Button Action too not Working.

```
 //ThirdTextField 
connectionNoText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 35)];
connectionNoText.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[connectionNoText setPlaceholder:@"Add directly or use me ->"];
connectionNoText.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
[connectionNoText setTag:2];
connectionNoText.delegate = self;
[connectionNoView addSubview:connectionNoText];

//addButton
addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
addButton.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 15, 15);
[addButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[addButton setEnabled:YES];
[connectionNoText addSubview:addButton];

-(IBAction)addButton:(id)sender
{
if (stateText.text.length == 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                                   message:@"Please select state first."
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"callpop");
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
AddAreaViewController * addAreaViewController = (AddAreaViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddAreaViewControlleridentifier"];
[self showPopupWithTransitionStyle:STPopupTransitionStyleSlideVertical rootViewController:addAreaViewController];
}
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
// Show UIPickerView
if (textField.tag ==0)
{
    NSLog(@"calling State");
    selectionVal = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        viewForPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-260,self.view.frame.size.width, 260);
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
else if (textField.tag ==1 )
{
    NSLog(@"calling Provider");
    if ([stateText.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self alert];
    }
   else
   {
       selectionVal = 2;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
           viewForPicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-260,self.view.frame.size.width, 260);
       }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        }];
   }
}
else if (textField.tag ==2)
{
    NSLog(@"clicked ConnectionN0");
}
[_statePickerView reloadAllComponents];

return NO;
}
```

Comment: whwere did u ca;ll the become first responder ?